# Using one database in flask and node.js | bcrypt

Tags: node.js, database, sqlite, flask, bcrypt

I have two apps A (flask) with login system and B (Node JS) without. Now I need to do login system for app B. Can I use sqlite database from my flask app? Basically passwords are encrypted with bcrypt in flask and I don't know if my login on Node Js will resolve password correctly or I need to make whole separate database for my Node app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach your flask app from Node.JS.
So, in Node.JS, when you want to login, make a login request your flask app and take token or secret key etc.

You can use same database.